# I want to delete a record from a file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I am developing an ATM Software System in which i am maintaining my database in text files. I want to delete a record from text file. My record is saved line by line in text file. I found an update code from internet but i want to delete account in this way. Please help me.

```
StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
string temp = "";
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Documents and Settings\john.grove\Desktop\1.txt");
foreach (string line in file)
{
    if (line.Contains("string"))
    {
        temp = line.Replace("string", "String");
        newFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");
        continue;
    }
    newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
}

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\john.grove\Desktop\1.txt", newFile.ToString());
```

Comment: It will be very inefficient for larger files. That's why most people store their database in a Database.

Comment: my requirement is text fie handling.

Comment: If the machine is turned off half-way through the WriteAllText operation, you'll lose your data. Are you sure you want to write your own persistence layer instead of using an embedded database?

Comment: do you have to use a text file?  seems like there are alot of better options out there.

Comment: aha again you and your ATM homework

Comment: @mekici: post a link if you have a dupe/related post

Comment: Would your requirements allow you to store your data in ado.net datatables (in memory)?  If so they are very easy to serialize and deseriaze into text files.  This would probably be more efficient than trying to implement updating/deleting/insertion logic from scratch.

Comment: @smoker - homework is not disallowed but if so then please state that it is. That avoids people investing energy in things outside your scope (like transactionality).

Answer (score 0):

You're better off streaming this:

```
string lines = File.ReadLines(path)
                   .Select(line => line.Replace("string", "String"));
File.WriteAllLines(newPath, lines);
```

Comment: And then maybe rename newPath to [old]Path